# No module named 'util' in Colab

Tags: python, import

I get an error when I try to import the util library in google colab. How can I fix it?

I tried :

```
!pip install utils
```

and

```
from util import *
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: `from utils import *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an 's' in `utils`

```py
!pip install utils
from utils import *
```